# Flutter: Failing to combine localisation with Provider package

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use localisation so that it is available from within my own Flutter plugin. To do this, I'm using an abstract base class called `CoreLocalisation`, which is implemented by my concrete `AppLocalisation` class. Then I'm using

```dart
List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> uiConsumableProviders = <SingleChildCloneableWidget>[
  ...
  Provider<CoreLocalisation>(
    create: (context) => AppLocalisation.of(context)
  )
];
```

I'm calling the `MultiProvider` from a `ContentPage`:

```dart
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  //final localisation = AppLocalisation.of(context);
  return MultiProvider(
    providers: uiConsumableProviders,
    child: ...
  );
}
```

What is confusing me is that the commented out call to `AppLocalisation.of(context)` works perfectly, but the invocation within the `MultiProvider` throws the following exception:

> FlutterError (inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_LocalizationsScope) or inheritFromElement() was called
>   before BuilderStateDelegate.initDelegate() completed.

In my understanding, the child context should have access to all of the elements available to the parent context. Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: The error is not saying that there is no such element in the tree. Instead, it is saying that you are calling it at the wrong time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `Localizations.of` (which calls `inheritFromWidgetOfExactType`) synchronously inside of `initState`, because the widget tree is still being built in that moment and you can't access inherited widget. You can call it using asynchronous callback:

```dart
Timer.run(() {
  AppLocalizations.of(this.context);
});
```

or from post-frame callback:

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  AppLocalizations.of(this.context);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve the problem explicitly, but I set up a workaround. First of all, I created a provider whose job was simply to convert a context into a concrete instance of `CoreLocalisation`. It used this class in the plugin:

```dart
class CoreLocalisationProvider {
  final CoreLocalisation Function(BuildContext) of;

  CoreLocalisationProvider(this.of);
}
```

Then the provider in the consuming app looked like this:

```dart
Provider<CoreLocalisationProvider>.value(value: CoreLocalisationProvider((context) => AppLocalisation.of(context)))
```

and I can add the following syntactic sugar to `CoreLocalisation`:

```dart
static CoreLocalisation of(BuildContext context) => Provider.of<CoreLocalisationProvider>(context).of(context);
```

This admittedly looks clumsy, but it permits me to use the familiar syntax `CoreLocalisation.of(context)` throughout the codebase, as if `CoreLocalisation` were a common-or-garden concrete localisation class.